# Lose coupled generic event handler implementation, request for comments

Tags: c#, generics, event-handling

I implemented the mediator pattern with a central event handler that other objects could raise events on and receive events from. My first implementation used regular events and would have issues with garbage collection, since (relatively) short lived objects would be subscribing to events from longer lived objects, so I redesigned it with WeakReference.

I threw something together, which seems to do the trick in a memory safe way using weak references and in a flexible way using generic methods, but then I realized an issue when garbage collection runs (tested with GC.Collect()) since all the weak references are killed off.

If this design even sound and if so, why on earth do weak references, pointing to active methods, get killed by garbage collection?

I made a very minimal self contained example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Events
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //int and bool are used for this example only to keep it very simple
            //In actual use it will be structs containing event data

            EventManager.RegisterEventHandler<int>(intHandler1);
            EventManager.RegisterEventHandler<bool>(boolHandler1);
            EventManager.RegisterEventHandler<int>(intHandler2);
            EventManager.RegisterEventHandler<bool>(boolHandler2);

            //generic type does not have to be explicit, since argument defines it
            //but I added for clarity here
            //raise a bool event and an int event, which each has two handlers at this point
            EventManager.RaiseEvent<bool>(true); 
            EventManager.RaiseEvent<int>(17);

            //remove one bool handler and then raise a bool event again
            //not only handled by the remaining handler
            EventManager.UnregisterEventHandler<bool>(boolHandler2);
            EventManager.RaiseEvent<bool>(false);

        }

        static void intHandler1(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IntHandler1 got " + i);
        }
        static void intHandler2(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IntHandler2 got " + i);
        }
        static void boolHandler1(bool b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BoolHandler1 got " + b);
        }
        static void boolHandler2(bool b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BoolHandler2 got " + b);
        }
    }


    public static class EventManager
    {
        //Given an instance of action<T>, create/find a list that can hold weak references
        //to that type of action, and add it to that list. Maintain a dictionary
        //referencing typeof(T) to the specific list holding that kind of action<T>
        public static void RegisterEventHandler<T>(Action<T> handler)
        {
            bool alreadyHasList = typeHandlerListDictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object handlerList);
            if (!alreadyHasList)
            {
                handlerList = new List<WeakReference<Action<T>>>();
                typeHandlerListDictionary.Add(typeof(T), handlerList);                
            }
            (handlerList as List<WeakReference<Action<T>>>).Add(new WeakReference<Action<T>>(handler));
        }

        //Given an instance of action<T>, find the list holding those actions as weak references 
        //and remove it from the list if found
        public static void UnregisterEventHandler<T>(Action<T> handler)
        {
            bool alreadyHasList = typeHandlerListDictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object handlerReferenceList);
            if (!alreadyHasList) throw new ArgumentException("The handler has not been registred");

            var list = handlerReferenceList as List<WeakReference<Action<T>>>;

            for (int i=0;i<list.Count;i++)
            {
                (list[i] as WeakReference<Action<T>>).TryGetTarget(out Action<T> thisHandler);
                if (thisHandler == handler)
                {
                    list.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Given an argument of type T, find the list holding weak references to any number of action<T> which 
        //can then be called with the argument
        public static void RaiseEvent<T>(T arg)
        {
            bool hasHandlerListForThisEventType = typeHandlerListDictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object handlerReferenceList);
            if (!hasHandlerListForThisEventType) return;

            foreach (var handlerReference in handlerReferenceList as List<WeakReference<Action<T>>>)
            {
                if (handlerReference.TryGetTarget(out Action<T> handlerAction))
                {
                    handlerAction.Invoke(arg);
                }
            }
        }

        //dictionary referencing typeof(T) to lists holding weak references to instances of action<T>
        static Dictionary<Type, object> typeHandlerListDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is silly. After typing the issue out, finding some problems, and fixing those, I have the answer. This could potentially be of interest to others, so I will answer and leave it. Vote to close and remove if you feel it is out of place.

When I pass an action along to the EventManager, that action may point to a method in an object, which is still alive, but the WeakReference is not to the object with the handler method, it is to the action, and that action itself has nothing pointing to it, except the WeakReference, therefore it can be collected.

The solution can then be to create the action, in the handler object, and store it as a member, so something references it, while the handler object lives, as is desired.

If this seems irrelevant to others, vote to close, and that is the end of it.